# Why should I use conditional stylesheets?

Tags: html, css

The question covers most of it, but I'm trying to present a well articulated argument towards a senior developer who wants to abandon conditional stylesheets altogether (IE6, mobile, etc). Bear in mind we're not actually eliminating IE6, just the stylesheet.

Or am I being crazy and should just accept this?

Comment: What's his argument as to why to remove them, and what is his suggestion for managing multiple browser compatibility?

Comment: What a compelling argument! ;)

Comment: He's been watching too much Project Runway

Comment: this senior developer is being unreasonable and turning one perfectly good solution into multiple problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the alternative?  CSS hacks?

I have conditional stylesheets for IE7 and IE6.  This compartmentalizes fixes for those specific browsers.  When making changes, it easily lets you test/fix in standards browsers, test/fix in IE7, then test/fix in IE6.  Testing flows more naturally.  It doesn't break standards, it's easy, and it's basically free.  It makes more sense to explain why you *wouldn't* use them.

Comment: This is my concern - he has not presented alternatives

Comment: Depending on office politics, I would probably call him out on it.  It's not a fight to lose your job over, but as bigmattyh pointed out, you'll lose a considerable amount of development time hacking the site into functionality compared to doing it The Right Way.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [Yahoo Reset CSS Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). It has eliminated the need for conditional stylesheets on many of the projects I've done.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't.  With enough work, both of the popular browsers can be made to render a page the same way. Take [mine](http://www.zi255.com) for example - Complex yet simple at the same time.

[edit: changed 'never' to 'you shouldn't', having thought the title said 'when']

Comment: How do you account for IE6-specific bugs like double margining and the broken box model without convoluted, divitis-inducing workarounds?

Comment: Agreed with the above.  "Never" doesn't always make sense for every design.  Also, it doesn't make sense to spend 3-4 hours of time on an IE-specific problem that can be fixed in 5 minutes with a targeted CSS rule in a conditional stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah and ugly, I'm not so sure I would be toting that as an example of a site that doesn't have conditional CSS.

Comment: And how is it complex? I don't see anything inherently complex about it, unless you mean how to follow it.

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't go beating my chest with a site that looks like that.

Comment: I didn't say it looked nice, I said it looks the same in IE6/7 and FF.

Comment: I wonder why people downvote this valid opinion. If you disagree, just vote up the other one.

Comment: @buti-oxa: I agree.  I'm surprised that this is being down-voted.  I understand that some layouts need browser-specific styling to work around bugs, but that doesn't mean that one should *try* to get as browser-neutral as possible and use browser-specific only when truly necessary.

Comment: Sorry I gotta agree with the others here - the sites I work on have to be pixel perfect and tableless. It's not really a solution to make it ugly across all browsers.

Comment: "pixel perfect" is an utterly ridiculous requirement. You guys must waste loads of time that could be better spent. (That being said, I agree most closely with @Eddie's comment, above).

Answer (score 0):

If you can meet your needs without conditional style sheets, then by all means it's a good idea to have a single style sheet for all browsers.  However, if you cannot do this without losing functionality, then a pretty good argument would have to be presented to justify going to a single style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Because IE 6 and IE 7 are broken in various well known ways. Conditional Stylesheets that modularize the *fixes* are the easiest and supported way to deal with these breaks.

When you say your senior developer wants to "abandon" conditional stylesheets, what exactly does that mean?