# Hack padding-right for IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to put padding-right:10px to my style for only IE , but I don't want other browsers to render this padding. Any solution to define padding only for IE, but protected from Firefox, chrome, and others?

Answer (score 8):

Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

**Edit**: If you really really want to hack the CSS - which you shouldn't - use

`* + HTML .myClass {}`

Which will target IE7 (I don't know how this works with IE8 in either mode - so please don't do it.)

Comment: other way please? I have tried _padding-right:10px but not work. thanks!

Comment: conditional comment isn't _property. check the link he gave

Comment: There is no other way. The "*+html" hack works for IE7 and IE8 in IE7-mode. What has "_padding-right:10px" to do with his answer?

Comment: You should also check http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/ie7-only-css-hacks-examples/

Answer (score 6):

[Conditional IE Rules](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
  /*For example, this creates special instructions for IE 6*/
  .myDiv { padding-right: 10px; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Make sure to respect the flow of your rules. You'll want this value to override any previous padding-right value, so place this *after* your other rules. Or you can add !important after the rule, giving you:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
  .myDiv { padding-right: 10px!important;
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

#### Stackoverflow Archive:

- [Do you put IE conditionals in the css file or in the html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570827/do-you-put-ie-conditionals-in-the-css-file-or-in-the-html-file)
- [CONDITION CSS differentiate between IE6 to IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115767/condition-css-differentiate-between-ie6-to-ie7)
- [Is there a way to do browser specific conditional CSS inside a *.css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639999/is-there-a-way-to-do-browser-specific-conditional-css-inside-a-css-file)
- [How can I have a CSS style different for IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987260/how-can-i-have-a-css-style-different-for-ie6)
- [css conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992871/css-conditional-formatting/992874)
- [IE CSS alignment issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531048/ie-css-alignment-issues/544092)
- [Why should I use conditional stylesheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526941/why-should-i-use-conditional-stylesheets)

Answer (score 0):

we use

`//padding-right: 10px;`

I guess every special character is ignored by every other browser..

Answer (score 0):

I am using
*padding:xx; 
Solved my problem.